# Why did the $2 bill lose its cash value?

Tags: united-states, currency, usd-us-dollar, legal-tender

The $2 bill used to be worth two dollars, (duh) but now it's worth nothing in most places. Why?

Comment: The two dollar bill is worth two dollars.  It is rarely used, but it hasn't ceased to be legal tender.

Comment: hey, what's with the downvotes?

Comment: "This question is not useful, or does not show any research efforts."

Comment: It's also wrong.  Depending of course on your definition of "most places".  Probably few people in the non-US world would want them, but I wouldn't want a low-denomination note of their currency, either.

Comment: @Imtherealsanic , questions that claim something that is incorrect, and then ask why it is so, get typically downvoted. if you did _any_ research, you would have known that your base statement is false.

Comment: I'll buy as many $2 bills I can afford at any price under $2 each.

Comment: The $2 bill is rare enough in circulation that there are more than a handful of ignoramuses who do not know they exist, therefore, they'd doubt their value and legitimacy.

Comment: While there's an occasional "news of the weird" where a cashier doesn't take a Jefferson $2, please clarify this question with an example of "most places"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [United States two-dollar bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_two-dollar_bill) is still legal tender, is still in production, and is still worth $2.

That having been said, something is worth only what someone will give you for it.  Pretend that I walk into a store with a pocket full of nothing but two-dollar bills, and the clerk in the store looks at them and says, "I don't recognize this.  It looks fake.  You can't use that here."  Those two-dollar bills are worth nothing to me at that moment.  However, if I go into a store next door where the clerk is a bit more sophisticated, they are then worth $2.

You might find yourself in a situation where someone is impressed by the two-dollar bill, having not seen it in years.  He might say to you, "Can I have one of those?  I'll give you three singles for it."  The bill is worth $3 at that moment.

Regardless, because it is legal tender, if you find yourself with two-dollar bills and you are having trouble finding a place to spend them, any bank should accept them and exchange them for a different denomination of currency.  I occasionally get a small stack of two-dollar bills from my credit union, just for fun.  People usually enjoy seeing them.

Comment: I have a friend that tips in $2 bills. He thinks it's fun.

Answer (score 9):

Presuming that this is the US, the $2 bill is still legal tender, and so is still worth $2.  [Source](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/faqs/Currency/Pages/denominations.aspx)

Comment: So it never lost it's cash value?

Comment: They are legal tender.  There may be businesses that choose not to accept them, just like businesses may choose to not accept bills over $20.  You could always go to a bank to change them into other denominations if it's a problem.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I have a stack of them, and they are doing fine. $1000 will buy 500 of these at my bank, and I go through them over a few years.

The premise of your question can use clarification. If a $1 bill still has value, then a $2 bill has twice that value. They are still printed, and still accepted as payment except by those who are so ignorant they don't believe they are real. Last time I was in NYC, I gave these away to those asking for money. Not one person called after me thinking it was a fake bill. A few gave me an extra thanks for a "Lucky $2"

Comment: Did you pull that out of your mattress?

Comment: Don’t be ridiculous. The mattress is just for the stack of $100s.

Answer (score 0):

> The two dollar bill used to be worth two dollars, (duh) but now it's worth nothing in most places. Why is this?

The strict answer to your question is *inflation*.  According to https://www.bls.gov/data/inflation_calculator.htm $2 in 1976 (when that bill was reissued) is now worth $0.45 (in 1976 terms).

But, as @Magua noted, it's still legal tender.  Thus, your question is quite confused.

Comment: I don't get in the OP that inflation is at the center of the question at all.

Comment: @fredsbend OP asks about *worth*, not whether the $2 bill is still legal tender.

Comment: Wow. Then a $1 bill is worth less than $0.25. That's pretty bad. We need to kill the penny, and the paper dollar in favor of dollar coins.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Canada occasionaly does things that the US should emulate, and two of them are the elimination of the 1 cent coin (in 2012) and $1 bill (replaced by $1 coin in 1987).

Comment: If we were going to emulate Canada, that wouldn’t hit my top ten. Just my opinion, but “not electing a sociopath to our highest office” would be the top item.